# Narrow and (vertically and horizontally) centralised fbox

Tags: arrays, alignment, fbox

Does anyone know how I can create a Narrow and (vertically and horizontally) centralised `\fbox`, whose content is an array.

For instance, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

    \fbox{$\begin{array}{c}
            0\\
            0
        \end{array}$}
\end{document}
```

which results in this:

[image]

But, note that, the box is not really narrow and the numbers are not vertically centralised in the box.

Could someone please help me?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\Shortstack{0 0}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, the stack is a "short" stack, providing a 3pt gap between [space separated] rows.  Gap size can be changed with `\setstackgap{S}{<gap size>}`.  Alternately, you can use a `\Longstack`, which is regulated not by a gap, but by a baselineskip. In that case, this macro call can change the default value: `\setstackgap{L}{<baseline skip>}`.

The small gap to the left/right of the zeroes are actually part of the glyph design and are called "sidebearings".  Their purpose is to provide default kerning between adjacent glyphs.

If you need it to function in math mode, `\stackMath` sets that as the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\stackMath
\fbox{\Shortstack{x y}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The default row separator (a space) can be changed with `\setstackEOL{<separator>}`.